# Jenkins on wamp build.xml ignore my ignoring folders

Tags: php, xml, build, jenkins, phpmd

I have a problem using build.xml in jenkins.
I have to exlude some directories when i exec phpmd, phpcs phpcpd, phpdoc, pdepend, phploc...
For each of these above, my --exclude or --ignore params is not working.... and my build on jenkins is so long.
I have to ignore some folder like (vendor(zend framework), js(for Jquery and jquery plugin), and some others like tests(for PHPunit))
This is my XML :

[See my XML on Pastie](http://pastie.org/8956095)

When i create this XML, i check on google some help and i found this :

[No luck tutorial](http://benjamin-balet.info/developpement/accelerer-lintegration-continue-dun-projet-php/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution after a lot of headhache :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<fileset id="php-files" dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="**/*.php"/>
    <exclude name="vendor/**"/>
    <exclude name="build/**"/>
    <exclude name="tests/**"/>
</fileset>

<target name="main" description="Start analyzing our application">
    <echo msg="Start Build" />

    <phingCall target="clean" />
    <phingCall target="prepare" />
    <phingCall target="phpunit" />
    <phingCall target="pdepend" />
    <phingCall target="phpmd-ci" />
    <phingCall target="phpcpd" />
    <phingCall target="phpdoc" />
    <phingCall target="phpcs-ci" />
    <phingCall target="phploc" />
    <phingCall target="phpcb" />

    <echo msg="Finished Build" />
</target>



<target name="clean" description="Delete old stuff">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
</target>

<target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="prepare new build">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
</target>

<!-- works perfectly -->
<target name="phploc" description="your project is too heavy loose weight fat boy">
    <exec executable="phploc.bat">
        <arg path="${basedir}/module" />
        <arg value="--log-csv" />
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
    </exec>
</target>
<!-- works perfectly -->
<target name="pdepend" description="more metrics chart please">
    <exec command="pdepend --jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml 
       --jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg 
       --overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg 
       --suffix=php
       --ignore=vendor,tests,build,public/js
       ${basedir}" 
    escape="false" />
</target>
<!-- works perfectly -->
<target name="phpmd-ci" description="Generate pmd.xml using PHPMD">
    <phpmd rulesets="codesize,design,naming,unusedcode">
        <fileset refid="php-files"/>
        <formatter type="xml" outfile="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd.xml"/>
    </phpmd>
</target>  
<!-- works perfectly -->
<target name="phpcs-ci" description="coding with checkstyle">
    <exec passthru="false" command="phpcs 
        --report=checkstyle
        --report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml
        --standard=Zend
        --ignore=vendor,tests,public/js,build
        --extensions=php
        ${basedir}"/>
</target>
<!-- Ne marche pas non plus en raison de : pas de test unitaire encore -->
<target name="phpcpd" description="repeat yourself is killing you">
    <exec executable="phpcpd">
        <arg line="--log-pmd ${basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
            --exclude ${basedir}/vendor
            --exclude ${basedir}/tests
            --exclude ${basedir}/build
            --exclude ${basedir}/js
            --suffixes php
            ${basedir}" />
        </exec>
</target>

<target name="phpdoc" description="Generate API documentation using PHPDocumentor">
    <phpdoc title="MyLink API Documentation"
          destdir="${basedir}/build/api"
          sourcecode="false"
          output="HTML:Smarty:PHP"
          quiet="true">
        <fileset refid="php-files"/>
    </phpdoc>
</target>

<target name="phpunit" description="test your code">
    <exec command="phpunit.bat 
    --bootstrap=${basedir}/tests/Bootstrap.php
    --configuration=${basedir}/tests/phpunit.xml
    --log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/junit.xml
    --coverage-clover ${basedir}/build/logs/clover.xml
    --coverage-html ${basedir}/build/coverage/"/>
</target>

<!-- works perfectly -->
<target name="phpcb" description="are you coding properly">
    <exec executable="phpcb.bat">
        <arg value="--log" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs" />
        <arg value="--source" />
        <arg path="${basedir}" />
        <arg value="--output" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/build/code-browser" />
        <arg value="--ignore"/>
        <arg path="${basedir}/vendor/,${basedir}/tests/,${basedir}/build/,${basedir}/public/js/"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The solution was to do some syntax adjustment, and use phing syntax either, especially phings call.

[This Phing build.xml was so usefull for this problem !!](https://github.com/albertogviana/phing-jenkins/blob/master/build.xml)

Hope this help someone, and convince others to work with Jenkins for Continuous Integration,  in Zend Framework projects !

Comment: You should accept your own answer to close the question

Comment: You right, but, i can accept my own answer in 2 days